# JWPlayer not playing MP4 on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, colorbox, jwplayer

I am using jwplayer player to load .mo4 video files in conjunction w/ the popular colorbox plugin (using inline html method).  Everything works on desktop browsers using mobile emulation, but the video will not play on mobile devices (testing on iPhone and Android).  Below is my code:

The following link is used to launch colorbox and load the inline HTML div#inline_content:

```
<a class="trailerVideo cboxElement" href="#inline_content" title="Video">
    <img src="assets/images/home-new/LookHear-AdmissionsVirtualTour.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Inline HTML div#inline_content containing JWPlayer loader:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="inline_content">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prebuilt/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <div id="myElement">Loading the player...</div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                flashplayer: "prebuilt/player.swf",
                file: "http://www.domain.com/media/mp4/virtual-tour-2013.mp4",
                image: "http://www.domain.com/images/home-new/LookHear-AdmissionsVirtualTour.jpg",
                height: 270,
                width: 480,
                plugins: { "googlytics-1": {} },
                autostart: true
            })
            $("#videoCaption").text(currCaption);
            function removePlayer() {
                jwplayer("myElement").remove();
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which gets rendered out as the following after loading JWPlayer flashplayer:

```
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="inline_content">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="prebuilt/jwplayer.js"></script>
        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="prebuilt/player.swf" width="480" height="270" id="myElement" name="myElement"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><param name="flashvars" value="id=myElement&amp;file=http%3A//www.domain.com/media/mp4/virtual-tour-2013.mp4&amp;image=http%3A//www.domain.com/images/home-new/LookHear-AdmissionsVirtualTour.jpg&amp;plugins=googlytics-1&amp;autostart=true&amp;controlbar.position=over"></object>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jwplayer("myElement").setup({
                flashplayer: "prebuilt/player.swf",
                file: "http://www.domain.com/media/mp4/virtual-tour-2013.mp4",
                image: "http://www.domain.com/images/home-new/LookHear-AdmissionsVirtualTour.jpg",
                height: 270,
                width: 480,
                plugins: { "googlytics-1": {} },
                autostart: true
            })
            $("#videoCaption").text(currCaption);
            function removePlayer() {
                jwplayer("myElement").remove();
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas why this would work on desktop browsers, but not work on mobile devices?  Note: by not working I mean not load the video on mobile (colorbox launches fine and loads other content just not the video).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're forcing JW Player into Flash mode, so it's not going to work on any mobile device - there's no Flash available there. The current version of JW Player doesn't use an <object> tag for embedding at all.

Comment: It looks like you are using JW5 here. Do you have a link to where this is running?

Comment: I checked the version they are running jwplayer.version="5.7.1896 (Licensed version)".  So it sounds like this is the issue?  Will need to upgrade to v6 or whatever the latest version is?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer The main site is (http://www.massart.edu). On the home page if you select LOOK/HEAR link it will launch current version of JW PLayer they are using.

Comment: How did you encode your mp4 file?

Comment: @Ethan JWPlayer I do not know. I am just doing a mobile project for the client.  I understand this detail may come into play, but will the issue most likely require an update?

Comment: I would try to do a re encode using - http://handbrake.fr/, just try default settings + web optimized.